# Error 1334 .File cannot be found in the Data1.cab

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, installation, cab

I am working on a Win 7-64 bit machine. I have a software installation package which contains the .msi file, a CAB file and some MST files. I wanted to modify the cabinet file. So I extracted the cab file using [CABARC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417343.aspx#cabarc) utility.

But before making any changes to the extracted files, just for testing the utility I removed the original cab file from the current directory. And created a new cab file from the files extracted from the original cab file, again using CABARC utility.

But now if I run the .msi file, it shows the error:

> ERROR:1334. The file "XYZ" cannot be installed because the file cannot be found in the cabinet file Data1.cab. This could indicate a network error, an error reading from the CD-ROM, or a problem with this package.

But the file is present in the cabinet file I can see that. The same installer is working fine with the original cab file.

I have tried different compression types (MSZIP, LZX:<15...21>) as well, but none of them work. I have not removed/added any file in the cabinet file. Am I doing anything wrong or if there is any other information that a cabinet file stores ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find anything out?

Comment: Did you get the solution for the above problem? Me too facing the same issue.

Comment: @mallikgm Sorry, I couldn't find the reason for this behavior.

Comment: Same issue here. Generates msi with wix, then ICE validates OK, and validates with `orca` ok.
If anybody knows anything please help

Comment: Still occurring in 2020.

Comment: fwiw, I had the same error today (file cannot be found in the cabinet file). The problem turned out to be a duplicate sequence number for the file that couldn't be found. The answer to [this question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c866557f-6ee4-4d28-996b-de9267e30553/error-1334-file-cannot-be-found-in-the-data1cab) also explains that the order and size of files must match the file table.

Answer (score 0):

This error when the setup path exceed the path limit for OS. Try changing output path for installer path to some shorter path.

Comment: Even though the path is shorter, this problem is occurring. Do you know any other reason for this?